# Listview adapter error, items random added

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I use a chat program with a node back-end and i use socket.io, server accepts data and sends them correctly.

But when i send messages only or receive messages only the last messages content changes like the last message content. As example 1st message:"dog", second message: "cat" when i press send on second message the 1st message and all previous messages if exist changes to "cat".

And if i try to send and receive messages the messages in the listview disappear one by one as i keep sending messages. As example if there is 10 Messages in the list as sent from me, when a message come from the server the messages in the list becomes 9, then 8, then 7, and so until it's empty.

I checked the ArrayList in the list adapter and it works correctly, i think the problem is in the getView() method in MessageListAdapter.java.

**activity_chat.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chat_activity_line"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chat_activity_line"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/chat_activity_line"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="#dfdfdf"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hide_border"
        android:onClick="activity_chat_send_message_btn"
        android:text="send"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="144dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="516dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_chat_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/ChatActivity_chat_box_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="197dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="552dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_chat.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_message_other"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_chat_other"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cairo"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="Hello Left"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_message_me"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/chat_message_other"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_message_other"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_chat_me"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cairo"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="Hello Right"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

**Message.java**

```
public class Message {
public String mssg, sender ;

public Message(){}

public Message(String mssg, String sender) {
    this.mssg = mssg;
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getMssg() {
    return mssg;
}

public void setMssg(String mssg) {
    this.mssg = mssg;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}
```

}

**MessageListAdapter.java**

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List<Message> list = new ArrayList<Message>();

public MessageListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

public void add(Message object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Message messgae = (Message) getItem(position);
    View row = convertView;
    ChatHolder chatHolder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_chat, parent, false);
        chatHolder = new ChatHolder();
        row.setTag(chatHolder);
    }
    else chatHolder = (ChatHolder) row.getTag();

    // linking views
    chatHolder.mssg_me = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_message_me);
    chatHolder.mssg_other = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_message_other);

    // condition for me and other
    if (messgae.getSender().equals("me")) {
        chatHolder.mssg_me.setText(list.get(list.size()-1).getMssg());
        chatHolder.mssg_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if (messgae.getSender().equals("other")) {
        chatHolder.mssg_other.setText(list.get(list.size()-1).getMssg());
        chatHolder.mssg_me.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return row;
}
static class ChatHolder {
    TextView mssg_me;
    TextView mssg_other;
   }
}
```

**Chat Activity.java**

```
private void send_newMessage_to_node(String mssg) {
    Message message = new Message(mssg, "me");

    chatListAdapter.add(message);
    chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // send to node server
    mSocket.emit("message", mssg);
}


private void addMessageFromNodeToListview(String mssg) {
    Message message = new Message(mssg, "other");

    chatListAdapter.add(message);
    chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: You're setting every item in the `ListView` to the last item in the list - `list.get(list.size()-1)`. That should be `list.get(position)` instead.

Comment: thanks Mike, that helped my first problem, but now when i send several messages from the android application it works correctly but when server send messages the list deletes messages one by one every time server send a message until the list is empty.

also if i start the list by server messages it works correctly and when i send a messages from the application list starts to delete items one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying, but in the `if-else if` in `getView()`, you need to reset the visibility on the other `TextView`. That is, in the `if` block, `chatHolder.mssg_me.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, and similarly for `mssg_other` in the `else if` block.

Comment: i totally forget, it solved my problem, man you saved my life thank you.

Comment: if you want put these two as answers to help any one find the same problem.

Comment: No problem. I'm on my phone at the moment, though, and I don't really wanna type out and format a full answer on this. Feel free to post your corrections in your own answer, if you like. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: ok and i will put your name in the answer, thanks again ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
1- for the problem of changing all list items content to be as the last item when i send or receive a message i had to change `list.get(list.size()-1)` to be `list.get(position)` as this was changing all list items.

2- for the problem of deleting an item every time i send or receive an item the solution was in the if-else if in getView(), i needed to reset the visibility on the other TextView. That is, in the if block, chatHolder.mssg_me.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);, and similarly for mssg_other in the else if block.

answered by [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)